# Swift 2.2 on ubuntu with package manager

Tags: swift, ubuntu, swift2

I'm trying to install Swift 2.2 and the swift package manager on ubuntu 15.10.

When I take a look at the [Swift Download Page](https://swift.org/download/#releases) there are 3 downloads available:

- `Swift 2.2` does not include the package manager
- `Trunk Development (master)` includes the package manager, BUT is swift 3.0
- `Swift 2.2.x Release Branch` does not include the package manager

What do I have to do to get Swift 2.2 with a working package manager?

Use an old `trunk` build before they began to develop `Swift 3.0`?

Grab the `Swift 2.2` release package, build [swift-lbuild](https://github.com/apple/swift-llbuild) to build `swift-build-tool` in order to build [swift-package-manager](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Swift 3.0’s package manager to build Swift 2.2 code:

```
export SWIFTC=path/to/swift-2.2/bin/swiftc
export PATH=path/to/swift-3.0/bin:$PATH

swift build
```

Comment: But would not that build using swift 3 compiler? I have a similar problem - I have a swift 2.2 package and I want it to be built with SPM. I got it with dev snapshot but it tries to build with swift 3 when I add it to $PATH. Module is not compatible with swift 3 so build fails. So I need to build using 2.2 compiler. $SWIFTC points to swiftc from 2.2.1 snapshot

Comment: As said, it will build with the Swift 2.2 compiler using the build engine from Swift 3.